# Railo, Tomcat IIS7 and default documents

Tags: tomcat, iis-7, railo, cfml

I've set up Railo v3.1 using Tomcat v6 - on a Windows 2008 (32bit) server.
Everything seems to work fine, except that no matter what I try, I can't get it to recognise my default document (index.cfm)

So:

http://localhost/index.cfm = fine

http://localhost = 404.3 error

If I look at the error, it seems that IIS7 is using the static file handler to process the file - As far as I can tell, the 404 error isn't referring to the file itself, but to the ISAPI handler used to process it.
Which doesn't make a great deal of sense.

I've tried adding a seperate handler in IIS7, but to no avail.

I think this is an issue in IIS7, as I've found several blogs and forum posts from people with similar problems, using a different system. (Tomcat, jBoss etc.)

Anyone come across this or have a workaround?

For details on my setup, I followed this guide rigidly:
http://www.hockeypfef.net/index.cfm/2009/3/12/Installing-Railo-3-on-Windows-200832bit-with-IIS7-and-Tomcat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting /*=wlb into the uriworkermap.properties file solved the problem.
I installed the jBoss MSI installer version and took a look at the properties files it had generated, to find this out!

Simple answer, but there we go.

Answer (score 1):

Did not see this post before but wanted to note that
I have created an alternate connector for Tomcat/Railo and IIS.
You can use it instead of the ISAPI connectors. The configuration is a little more straight forward as you can use IIS facilities to influence which files are beeing forwarded to Tomcat/Railo and also can pick the default document on the IIS side as well.
The connector can be downloaded from Riaforge:
http://tomcatiis.riaforge.org
Manual installation instruction and an automated installer is also included in the package.
Feedback can be left on Riaforge site.

Comment: I resolved this issue some time ago, but your connector looks like a good option. I'll give it a go next time I need to set up a Railo server. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I know your going through tomcat, but if your on IIS it does not automatically forward all requests to the railo server, only ones you have defined in your worker configuration(maybe just .cfm/.cfc).  Which is why .cfm explicit works and nothing sends a 404.

In the IIS manager under the  properties for your default localhost site and in the documents tab, did you make the default page index.cfm?

[instructions via microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/dc6eb1b4-9028-4308-9935-52b64edfad36.mspx?mfr=true)

[edit]
Also you might check your uriworkermap.properties
set /*=wlb instead of the /*.cfm, basically forward anything and everything to tomcat.

Comment: Yes, I've set up the default document in IIS.
The error shows index.cfm as the requested file - however it states that the handler is 'StaticFile' with the 'StaticFileModule' module. I've tried putting index.cfm in the uriworkermap.properties file, as well as specifying the welcome file in web.xml.

Comment: what happens if you set *=wlb instead of the *.cfm, basically forward anything and everything to tomcat

Answer (score 0):

You ought to mark your comment as the answer, so the question is marked as answered.

BTW, for those interested in running Railo, CF, or Open BD on Tomcat, Matt  Woodward will be speaking on that this week at the [Online ColdFusion Meetup](http://www.coldfusionmeetup.com), in the 6pm slot on Thursday April 16.